# how does ML finds difference between pair and arguments in a program?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, ml

for example the following code

```
fun swap (pr : int*bool) =
(#2 pr, #1 pr)

fun div_mod (x : int, y : int) = 
(x div y, x mod y)
```

the above code has taking **pair(Tuple)** as an argument in the first **swap** function , and taking two integers as an argument in function **div_mod** ..so my doubt is how does ML know that am calling it with a **pair**(Tuple) and not calling  it with **two arguments** ?

please help me . am beginner in ML programming
Thank you :)

Comment: there are some things I don't understand in your question: - what has this to do with `emacs`? What is the reason you added `sum_two_pairs`? In the end I think you just asking if `((x,y) : int*int)` is the same as `(x:int,y:int)` as argument definitions - if this **is** your question then the answer is yes

Comment: okay @Carsten I edited my question ..now did you understand what's my doubt ? if you don't it's okay I can understand what you didn't understand .. :)  thank you for your  answer :)

Comment: there is no difference - your *two arguments* there **is** a pair - indeed no function has more than one argument - it either takes one and returns another function (*currying*) or it takes tuples.

Comment: @Carsten this is not right, functions can take more than one argument in SML, at least in syntax:  `fun maketriple a b c = (a, b, c);;` results in
`val maketriple = fn: 'a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'a * 'b * 'c` (checked in poly)

Comment: @Str depending on what level we are talking here this does not need to be a function of 3 parameters - AFAIK it's true for ML as well that this type is equivalent to `'a -> ('b -> ('c -> 'a*'b*'b))` - so it's a function taking one value (a `'a`) and returns another function (of type `'b -> ('c -> 'a*'b*'c)`) - this is one of the great things functional programming gives us ;)

Comment: @Carsten please reread my comment, I think you are mixing up the levels. You should not say "this does not exist" when you can write it.

Comment: I can argue that what you call multiple arguments are not - it's a higher order function instead - a fact you can easily check if you partially apply only one argument

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the types themselves, both functions take one argument, which is a pair.

These two definitions are equivalent to yours:

```
fun swap (i: int, b: bool) = (b, i)
fun div_mod (xy: int * int) = ((#1 xy) div (#2 xy), (#1 xy) mod (#2 xy))
```

The only difference is whether you do pattern matching against the elements of the tuple or not.

There's a slight difference in whether you would *say* that a function takes one or two arguments, though.
If the pair is just "incidental" – used for grouping like in these functions – you often say that the function takes two arguments.
If the pair represents some kind of abstraction like, say, a rational number, you would probably say that it takes one argument.

Comment: oh yeah ..:) understood..:) Thank you so much @molbdnilo

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check it in your preferred SML:

```
str@s132-intel:~> poly
Poly/ML 5.5.2 Release
>fun swap (pr : int*bool) = (#2 pr, #1 pr);;
val swap = fn: int * bool -> bool * int
> 
> fun div_mod (x : int, y : int) = (x div y, x mod y);;
val div_mod = fn: int * int -> int * int
```

The first takes type `int * bool`, the second takes `int * int`, both are pairs.

In contrast, multiple arguments which are not tuples:

```
> fun maketriple a b c = (a, b, c);;
val maketriple = fn: 'a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'a * 'b * 'c
```

And how does SML tell the types of arguments apart? Tuples are written inside parens and separated by commata.